# React Material UI TextField FormHelperTextProps Styling Not Working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield, styling

I'm trying to style the helper text that comes with the TextField Component given by Material UI ( found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/)). I'm using FormHelperTextProps (found [here](https://material-ui.com/api/form-helper-text/)). However, it seems that, for some reason,  the styling I'm writing is not being applied to the component itself. I would appreciate any help I could get on this. Here is my code:

```
    const useHelperTextStyles = makeStyles(()=> ({
    root: { 
        "& .MuiFormHelperText-root" : { color: TextFieldColours.error["status-text"] }, 
        // "& .MuiFormHelperText-contained"
    }
    })
     );

    const EmptyTextField = (props: CustomEmptyFieldProps) => {
    const {
         usernameOrPass,
    } = props; 
    const inputLabel = "VolunteerHub " + usernameOrPass; 
    const errorMessage = "Please enter your VolunteerHub " + usernameOrPass; 

    const textFieldStyles = useTextFieldStyles(false);
    const helperTextStyles = useHelperTextStyles(); 
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField
                className={textFieldStyles.root}
                placeholder={inputLabel}
                id="outlined-error-helper-text"
                defaultValue=""
                helperText={errorMessage}
                variant="outlined"
                FormHelperTextProps={{
                    classes={helperTextStyles.helperText,}
                }}
            />
        </div >
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all a class needs to targetted in classes prop, like `root`, `focused` etc. so in classes props select pass the style to the `root` class. And another issue is there is no `helperText` class in `useHelperTextStyles` hook.
So for targeting the root style the code will like this:

```
const useHelperTextStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
        color: TextFieldColours.error["status-text"]
    }
}));

const EmptyTextField = (props) => {
    const { usernameOrPass } = props;
    const inputLabel = "VolunteerHub " + usernameOrPass;
    const errorMessage = "Please enter your VolunteerHub " + usernameOrPass;

    const textFieldStyles = useTextFieldStyles(false);
    const helperTextStyles = useHelperTextStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField
                className={textFieldStyles.root}
                placeholder={inputLabel}
                id="outlined-error-helper-text"
                defaultValue=""
                helperText={errorMessage}
                variant="outlined"
                FormHelperTextProps={{
                        classes:{
                            root:helperTextStyles.root
                        }
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Here is a working demo:

[image: Edit quizzical-bash-ggynj]

Answer (score 2):

In MUI v5 you can just use the `MuiFormHelperText` component in your theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    ...
      MuiFormHelperText: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            color: colors.error.main
            }
          }
        }
     ...
  }
})
```

With the API docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-helper-text/